# Kivy Atlas loading fails

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

StackOverflow
I have a little problem with kivy when I'm trying to load a pic from atlas:

```
D:\Games\Projects\python>py -2 test.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\%username%\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-03-05_70.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <.\my.kv>
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] kv <.\my.kv> not found
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load <images\a.atlas>
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Need to load 1 images
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load <images\a-0.png>
[DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load <D:\Games\Projects\python\images\a-0.png>
[TRACE  ] [Image       ] u'D:\\Games\\Projects\\python\\images\\a-0.png', populate to textures (1)
```

a.atlas:

```
{
  "a-0.png": {
    "logo": [1291, 728, 326, 93],
    "jill": [0, 0, 644, 364]
  }
}
```

test.py:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy import resources
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.atlas import Atlas
from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')
Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'trace')

class MyApp(App):

  def build(self):
    tt = Atlas('./images/a.atlas')
    return Image(source='atlas://images/a/logo', pos=[100, 100], size=[326, 93])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  MyApp().run()
```

Now it's just a test. I am trying to learn kivy, but something going wrong
Anyone knows why this can happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2780), and as one of the [comments](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2780#issuecomment-68109530) indicates:

> i think the issue is that the saving in its current form requires the
>   creation of a texture, and in this test, it happens that no opengl
>   context have been created, a simple workaround is to add:
>
> `from kivy.core.window import Window` or
>
> `from kivy.base import EventLoop EventLoop.ensure_window()` at the top
>   of the script.
>
> It works for me after that.
>
> I don't think it's actually a bug, since we don't promise image
>   manipulation without the creation of an opengl context, but maybe we
>   could call ensure_window() in Image.save().

So you should only use the following:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.atlas import Atlas
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):

  def build(self):
    tt = Atlas('images/a.atlas')
    return Image(texture=tt["logo"], pos=[100, 100], size=[326, 93])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  MyApp().run()
```

Also if you do not want to use that you can eliminate the use of Atlas:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class MyApp(App):

  def build(self):
    return Image(source='atlas://images/a/logo', pos=[100, 100], size=[326, 93])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, both of variants doesn't work at all. Just black screen and nothing

Comment: @KseniaK. You can share your zipped project.

Comment: @KseniaK. I think the problem is your image, you could share the original zipped image so that the internet does not modify it, I have used another image and if it works correctly

Comment: [original image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gyrkyfwbhb4q1o/a-0.zip?dl=0)
I just re-saved it with photoshop trying to fix everything

Comment: ok, problem solved. I'm counting coords from upper-right corner, but kivi counts from bottom-right

Comment: @KseniaK. OKay, I also just realized that, if my answer helped you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]